# db2 fetch one row from another file, based on max datetime and status

Tags: sql, db2

I'm looking and I'm kinda lost again. The most related thread I could find was this http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1173569

So what I'm trying to do is get a select statement that reads the latest date and time from another table if the id and status matches.

I've come across a few issues when I do this. I either time out because the query is too big, there's duplicate id's due to there being multiple date and times, or I have some kind of syntax error.

The programmer created two logical files for me to use, since I was having so much trouble with the history file. The first logical contains the history with the status of 'CLO'. The second logical contains the history with the status of 'LOA'.

But when I try to do an inner join with both logicals, using an aggregate function max() on date and time, it never finishes loading.

And if I try fetch first 1 ROWS only in a subselect, the syntax is either wrong, or I end up with one row overall instead of the table I was trying to inner join.

Just to clarify, the end result is that I want two separate columns joined to my main table.  The Max(datetime) of 'CLO' and the max(datetime) of 'LOA'.

WANTED COL1 is CASE WHEN CURRENT STATUS = CLO THEN MOST RECENT DATE TIME WITH CLO ELSE NULL

WANTED COL2 will always display, but it's also MOST RECENT DATE TIME WITH LOA

```
╔════════╦════════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗  
║ KEY ID ║ CURRENT STATUS ║ WANTED COL1 ║ WANTED COL2 ║  
╠════════╬════════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣  
║    111 ║ CLO            ║ 1/1/2015    ║ 12/31/2014  ║  
║    112 ║ LOA            ║ null        ║ 12/31/2014  ║  
║    113 ║ LOA            ║ null        ║ 1/1/2015    ║  
╚════════╩════════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

And the history file I have is like this.

```
╔════════╦════════════╦══════╦══════════════╗  
║ KEY ID ║ DATE       ║ TIME ║ STATUS       ║  
╠════════╬════════════╬══════╬══════════════╣  
║ 111    ║ 1/1/2015   ║ 1025 ║ CLO          ║  
║ 111    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 555  ║ LOA          ║  
║ 111    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 333  ║ OTHER STATUS ║  
║ 113    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 333  ║ LOA          ║  
║ 112    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 333  ║ OTHER STATUS ║   
║ 112    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 333  ║ LOA          ║   
╚════════╩════════════╩══════╩══════════════╝
```

But the logicals that were made for me were dumbed down to this.

```
╔════════╦════════════╦══════╦════════╗   
║ KEY ID ║ DATE       ║ TIME ║ STATUS ║   
╠════════╬════════════╬══════╬════════╣   
║ 111    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 555  ║ LOA    ║   
║ 111    ║ 12/30/2014 ║ 555  ║ LOA    ║   
║ 111    ║ 12/25/2014 ║ 555  ║ LOA    ║   
║ 113    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 333  ║ LOA    ║   
║ 112    ║ 12/31/2014 ║ 333  ║ LOA    ║   
╚════════╩════════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

@danny117
I tried this query, but it's showing me an error.  [SQL0338] JOIN predicate not valid.

```
        WITH cteLOA AS
        (
            SELECT temp_tableLOA.Date || ' ' || temp_tableLOA.Time AS oneDATETIMELOA
            FROM /**/ temp_tableLOA
            ORDER BY oneDATETIMELOA DESC
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
        ),
        cteCLO AS
        (
            SELECT temp_tableCLO.Date || ' ' || temp_tableCLO.Time AS oneDATETIMECLO
            FROM /**/ temp_tableCLO
            ORDER BY oneDATETIMECLO DESC
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
        )
            SELECT 
            /*other columns*/
            cteLOA.oneDATETIMELOA AS HISTORYDATETIMELOA,
            CASE WHEN /**/STAT = 'CLO ' THEN cteCLO.oneDATETIMECLO ELSE NULL END AS HISTORYDATETIMECLO

        FROM /**/ vu, cteLOA, cteCLO

        /* Insert other inner joins, where logic, group bys, yada yada */
```

Comment: Add table definitions, sample data, and wanted output, and it will be much easier to assist you!

Comment: Okay, I've added the tables.  From what I searched and previewed, this was the best formatting I could find, using http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Please include the OS version/release and the platform. Is this iSeries DB2? If so, we should also see the definitions of the `logical files`, e.g., do they use DDS select/omit or other non-SQL facilities?

Comment: I'm using v6r1m0.  Yes this is the iSeries DB2.  I do not know what DDS Select/omit is.

Answer (score 0):

All the columns one row with low date and high date joined by id something like this.

```
with cte as (                             
SELECT * FROM mytable where stat = "CLO" ORDER BY xDATE desc 
fetch first 1   rows only                 
) select * from cte                       
join mytable on cte.id = mytable.id where stat = "OPN" order by            
mytable.xdate                             
fetch first 1 rows only
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  I've not used cte before so maybe that's why.  Where would I put my main table's code with all of its inner joins, where logic, and stuff?

Comment: CTE is common table expression.  You can use any identifier you want.  Common table expressions start with "With".  It's like a two step query.  first the common table expression is executed and it returns rows.  Use the returned rows in another query typically you join to the common table expression.  I'd suggest searching for a few tutorials on common table expression.   https://www.google.com/#q=common+table+expression